# Jquery to sort gridview columns at client side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery

How can I using JQuery sort any column of gridview at client side? Kindly share...

Comment: Check this article may help you : [Sorting Gridview using Jquery with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TableBlueSorter.aspx) [Sortable GridView using jQuery's TableSorter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/SortableGridViewjQuery.aspx)

Comment: I want to sort the tables at the client side itself without doing any post-back or any communication with the server.

Comment: as per your question you asked for the gridview control and this article are related to that only

Comment: thanks... i was missing some key points... thanks for ur help

Answer (score 2):

There's the [jQuery TableSorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) I tend to use for this.

Comment: @HotTester - yep, it's just a table, all you have to do is disable the default ASP.Net sorting, let it render as *just* table.

Comment: Can you share the code for the same... for it is not running the way you are saying... thanks...

Comment: @HotTester -I'm not following *what* isn't working? All you have to do is call `$("#tableId").tablesorter();` inside a `document.ready` handler, there's no other setup.

Comment: Thanks @Nick ... i got it... actually gridview by default does not render the tbody tag that is needed for the tablesorter. I just added GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

Answer (score 1):

This is probably [the most straight-forward article on this subject](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=2168345).

It is based on [jQuery TableSorder plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) that **Nick Craver** mentioned... I just didn't like official documentation and wanted to share article with others.